# add/insert page to existing pdf form fields using itextsharp

Tags: itext

Has anyone used itextsharp to add/insert a pdf form to another form and not lose the form fields.  I tried it and it doesn't retain the form fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please read [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of my book "iText in Action". It explains that you lose fields when using `PdfWriter` or `PdfCopy` and it explains that you should use the `PdfCopyFields` class.